# Sanitize input before storing into database

Tags: php, html, htmlspecialchars, addslashes

First of all, I have a html editor that accept input from user. I want to store plain html tags in database and cater for quotes (sql injection) that appear as well.

For example,

```
$input = "<h1><strong><span style="font-size:36px">I'm waiting</span></h1>";
```

I need to cater quote only from **I'm waiting** but not quotes that appear between html tags before storing into database. Any recommended way to do that?

> ps: please ignore PDO (or mysqli) with prepared statements in this case.

Comment: Did you try using `htmlentities()`

Comment: what are u receiving from database??

Comment: Why do you want to treat the html tags and the text in between differently. They are both user input ans a security risk for sql injection the same way

Comment: @Gavriel if this is the case, should I use addslashes() before inserting into database and use stripslashes() for retrieving data?

Comment: without any use of an escaping function/prepared statement, anything other than that leaves you open to an SQL injection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

You should use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php to make sure no sql injection can be made against you.

Comment: Telling someone to use a deprecated method isn't a good idea.

Comment: @MattStephens, on the other hand telling someone that something is deprecated without telling what to use instead is very helpful